# counting letters in a sentence

Tags: php

How do you calculate number of letters in a sentence like below using PHP?

hello how are you

`strlen` gives total number including spaces.

Comment: do you want only letters, or any non-space character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$letter_count = strlen( $string ) - substr_count($string , ' ');`

This is the total length - the number of spaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can strip out the spaces with [`str_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$stripped = str_replace(' ', '', 'hello how are you');
```

Then it's easy to count the remaining characters.

Answer (score 0):

You could first remove all non-letters:

```
$result = preg_replace('/\P{L}+/u', '', $subject);
```

and then do `mb_strlen($result)`.

`\p{L}` is the regular expression for "any Unicode letter".

`\P{L}` is its inverse - anything but a letter.

Comment: Why go to the trouble of using a unicode-safe regex, to potentially get the wrong number of *letters* by using `strlen()`?

Comment: @salathe: Oh, so `strlen()` counts the number of bytes, not the number of characters (I don't know PHP)? Is there a function that will work correctly with Unicode strings?

Comment: `mb_strlen()`. All the multi-byte-aware string functions are under the `mb_` prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite `strlen` that doesn't count spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'hello how are you';
$spaceless = str_replace(' ','',$string);
$totalcharswithspaces = strlen($string);
$totalchars = strlen($spaceless);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want frequency information too...

```
$strip_chars = array(" "); //this is expandable now
$array_of_used_characters = count_chars(str_replace($strip_chars, '', $sentence), 1);
var_dump($array_of_used_characters);
```

Comment: oops. :) sorry... I'm too tired for this.